# Evaluating an integral using MCMC algorithm

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, numerical-integration

Consider the problem of evaluating the following integral
$$ \int_T f(\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3| D) d\Theta$$
where $f$ is a posterior density and the values of $D = (d_1, ..., d_n)$, given $\Theta$ are $i.i.d$ with a given distribution and $T$ has the following form:

$$T = \{(\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3) \in M | f(\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3|D) > k \} $$

for $k$ a known constant bigger than zero and $M=(0,\infty)$x$(1,\infty)$x$(0,\infty)$

I don't know how to apply $MC$ integration method to solve this integral, since I can't see how is this region $T$ or even how to write its volume. I thought we could use the distribution of $d|\Theta$, but I don't know how to.

I would be glad if I could have some help understanding better how to calculate this integral

Thanks!

(P.S: I will use the metropolis hastings to sample from $f$, thats why I wrote MCMC)

Comment: I don't understand if you are treating D in your problem as a fixed value (calculate the integral given D) or as a random variable (maybe you are looking for $\int_T f(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3|D)p(D|\Theta)d\Theta)  )

Comment: @Giancarlo please see my edit. What I need to do is a hipotesis test, so $D$ is a vector of random variables. Of course that to find my posterior, I need to have an observation, which is given (i.e, I have an observed data so I know how my posterior $f$ is). The integral I am looking for is exactly what I wrote before.

Comment: What I tried to tell is that the function is known, but my problem is to integrate over this region.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If I get it right, you have an unnormalized posterior, which you can sample from with MH, but you need the normalized posterior f to calculate T. Since your dimensions are low (three), why not calculating the normalization constant of the posterior with numerical integration? Once you have your normalized posterior, you can solve the integral.

Comment: @Giancarlo Because it is asked to use MCMC and I don't know how to use it over this region. Thanks for your help, btw

Comment: from your question, f is a posterior, not a likelihood function, in which case you do need a normalizing constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can calculate the value of $f(\Theta|D)$ for a given $\Theta$, then the problem can be solved in the following way:

1. Consider the function
   $$g(\Theta|k) = 1\;  \mathrm{if}\;  f(\Theta|D) < k, \; 0 \; \mathrm{otherwise}$$
   Your integral becomes
   $$ \int_M g(\Theta|k)f(\Theta|D) d\Theta $$
2. Using MCMC get n samples $S^{(j)}, j = 1\ldots n$ from the posterior $f(\Theta|D)$ , and then approximate the integral as
   $$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^n g(S^{(j)})$$

If you don't have a normalized posterior, you can still compute the evidence as
$$ \int_M L(D|\Theta) p(\Theta)d\Theta $$  (by taking samples from the prior and averaging the likelihood over those samples), normalize the posterior and then use the two previous points.

Comment: If I use Metropolis Algorithm, I don't need an normalized posterior. Thank you very much for your help!